# Custom CSS associated with just one page?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a wordpress site which only allows to to add customs css (basically). I have a css code  and the page id is 108.

I found online someone suggested something like:

```
.your_ID h2 {display:none;}
```

but how do I correctly insert my id into that?

My code is:

```
project-image figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    background: transparent;
    color: #111;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

ID indicate with "#"

```
#your_ID {"Your css here"}
```

Answer (score 0):

@user3604485, for selecting `ID's we use #` and for selecting `class .` i.e.

```
#your_ID h2 {display:none;} //this is for ID

.your_Class h2 {display:none;} // this css is basically for your class
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give Class or Id to your image for example:

**Id** is **project-image** then use this css with Id selecter `#`

```
#project-image  {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    background: transparent;
    color: #111;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    }
```

if you want to use **Class** like **project-image** then use this css with class selector `.`

```
.project-image{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    background: transparent;
    color: #111;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    }
```